# Binary Search Tree C++ Implementation(dynamic memory problems)

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am currently learning how to implement a binary search tree, but using a more rudimentary C approach(please no "use classes now"). However, there is a big problem with dynamic memory getting itself deleted. The head value gets updated correctly, however, every other point gets itself deleted. Can anyone help me? Also, it would be nice if you would offer some tips how to tighten up my implementation of the tree. A basic rundown of the program: you input a character and thus you run one of the tree's functions. Mind though, that this implementation is a pure BST, so no balancing. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>

struct point{
    point* parent, *left, *right;

    int val = -1;
};

point* biggest;
point empty;

point search(int pos, bool near, point* loc = biggest){
    if(loc->val == pos){
        return *loc;
    } else if(loc->left->val != -1 and loc->val > pos){
        return search(pos, near, loc->left);
    } else if(loc->right->val != -1){
        return search(pos, near, loc->right);
    }

    if(near){
        return *loc;
    } else{
        point fail;
        return fail;
    }
}

void insert(int pos, point* res){
    point loc = search(pos, true);
    res->val = pos, res->left = &empty, res->right = &empty, res->parent = &loc;
    if(loc.val < res->val){
        loc.left = res;
    } else{
        loc.right = res;
    }

}

void remove(int pos){

}

int pred(int pos){
    point res = search(pos, false);
    if(res.val == -1){
        return -1;
    }

}

int succ(int pos){
    point res = search(pos, false);
    if(res.val == -1){
        return -1;
    }

}

void inorder(point* pos = biggest){
    if(pos->left->val != -1){
        inorder(pos->left);
    }
    std::cout << pos->val << " ";
    if(pos->right->val != -1){
        inorder(pos->right);
    }
}

int main() {
    point start;
    start.parent = &empty, start.left = &empty, start.right = &empty;
    biggest = &start;
    char c;
    int pos;
    do{
        std::cin >> c >> pos;

        switch (c){
            case 'S':
                std::cout << search(pos, false).val << std::endl;
                break;
            case 'I':
                if(biggest->val == -1){
                    start.val = pos;
                } else{
                    point* res = new point;
                    insert(pos, res);
                }
                break;
            case 'R':
                remove(pos);
                break;
            case 'P':
                std::cout << pred(pos) << std::endl;
                break;
            case 'N':
                std::cout << succ(pos) << std::endl;
                break;
            case 'O':
                inorder();
                std::cout << std::endl;
                break;
        }
    } while(c != '0');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `point* res = new point;` 
The tree should be responsible for creating the nodes, not `main()`.  What good is a data structure if the user is doing a chunk of the work that the data structure should be responsible for?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The first thing I tried was the "constructing" being done by the function. I changed that to a probably botched constructor, then I changed it to this code.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from much weirdness in your code I would say that here :

```
void insert(int pos, point* res){
    point loc = search(pos, true);
    res->val = pos, res->left = &empty, res->right = &empty;
    res->parent = &loc; // <=== here
```

you modify `res->parent` to point at a local variable `loc`. After the `insert()` function returns the `point loc` does not exist anymore.

Also you *are* already using classes; C++ structs and classes are pretty much identical ... apart from the default member visibility.

Comment: Yes, that is the problem that I searched for(dynamic memory getting itself deleted). How would it be possible to avoid the deletion?

About the second point, yes that's right. I mostly meant about encapsulation(another thing, why encapsulation? In theory, encapsulation is more for the compiler, right?).

Comment: The `search()` function should return a pointer. Then *it* can do the allocation of the new node if needed (i.e. when `near == true` and the exact value is not found). Encapsulation is not for the compiler, it is mostly used to keep program data and functions that operate on that data together. It is more maintainable that way.